# Using JFrog Artifactory Deployer with a shared UNC path

Tags: artifactory, azure-pipelines, vnext

We are using JFrog Artifactory with TFS 2017 and I am looking to use the JFrog Artifactory Deployer task with my build. Looking to upload artifacts from a shared UNC part. Whilst it works fine when uploading artifacts from local file system, it doesn't work with UNC path. I tried using mapped drive but that didn't work either. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Getting the following error

> running 'C:\agent_work\16\a\jfrog.exe' rt upload
>   '\myshared\drops\BuildName\BuildVersion\**\*.zip' 'ext-repo'
>   --url=https://aritfactory/artifactory --user=******** --password=******** --props='build.number=2996783;build.name=ArtifactoryUpload' 2017-05-22T15:23:06.5911571Z  2017-05-22T15:23:06.5911571Z 
>   2017-05-22T15:23:06.8240199Z Pinging Artifactory...
>   2017-05-22T15:23:07.0369535Z Done pinging Artifactory.
>   2017-05-22T15:23:07.0369535Z Path does not exist:
>   \myshared\drops\buildName\BuildVersion 2017-05-22T15:23:07.0838234Z
>
> ### [error]Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Deployment to Artifactory failed 2017-05-22T15:23:07.0994475Z ##[error]PowerShell
>
> script completed with 1 errors. 2017-05-22T15:23:07.0994475Z
>
> ### [section]Finishing: JFrogArtifactoryDeployer

Comment: What's the result if you run jfrog command with a shared folder manually?

Comment: It's the same error

Comment: So, I think the shared folder is not supported for jfrog, you need to copy files.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy files to a local folder by using [Copy Files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files) or [Windows Machine File Copy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy) task, then upload artifacts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, that's an option but given the size of Artifacts, it is an inefficient process.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is that adding a powershell script task in your build definition to map the network drive and then publish to artifacts. I just did a quick test with it and it works. the powershell script I used:

```
New-PSDrive -Name "G" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\UNC\Path"

cd G:\

./jfrog.exe rt upload folder\\file.txt 'example-repo-local' --url=https://xxxxx.jfrog.io/xxxx/example-repo-local/ --user='xxxxx' --password='xxxxx' --props='build.number=001;build.name=BuildName'
```

Remember to download the "jfrog.exe" and place it in the UNC Path.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to make a symbolic link of the data folder and copy the contents of the data folder into the symbolic link than restart Artifactory.